# Java Keystore - Where to store the 'Master Password'?

Tags: java, swing, keystore, keychain

I am developing a Java Swing app that needs to hold passwords to remote servers. I have decided to use the KeyStore to accomplish this.

I store each password under an Alias/Master Password and retrieve them using the same Alias/Master Password.

My question is:

Where should the Master Password be stored?

This is not a cheap attempt at a paradox but a serious question and I am interested in knowing how this problem can be solved.

I don't have any real experience in this area and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I store each password under an Alias/Master Password and retrieve them
>   using the same Alias/Master Password.

There is a misunderstanding here.
 The keystore is a container for your private credentials and trusted certificates and **not** just some generic database/hashtable to store passwords.

The best approach would be to store the hash of the password in the database.

> Where should the Master Password be stored?

This is a very common problem that comes up very frequent.
Just keep it in your source code which, yes can be decompiled, but delegate the responsibility to the user to keep his account private so that this files are not stolen/examined e.g via a decompiler

Comment: OSX stores generic passwords in its KeyChain, so Apple accept that it can be used for such.

Comment: I don't want users having to enter a password every time they start my app running. So, the only acceptable thing is to store the Master Password. A digest does not solve the problem as the user would have to enter the password...

Comment: @Lyndon:I don't follow:If the user does not provide anything how can you retrieve the password using the alias/password association?

Comment: The Keychain in OSX is accessed using the logged in user's password (I believe). Permission is asked by the OS to access the Keychain. I am developing on OSX but I don't want to use the OSX Keychain as I will also deploy to Windows. For the time being I have hardcoded the Master Password but the problem remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

The master password should either:

- be given online by the user
- or be stored encrypted with a user-given password. This last should be informed online by the user.

Comment: As above, I don't want my users to have to eneter a password every time they run my app.

Comment: According to Raph Koster: "Never trust the client.
Never put anything on the client. The client is in the hands of the enemy. Never ever ever forget this." (http://www.raphkoster.com/gaming/laws.shtml)